# jquery ui tooltip remains visible for the controls under ajax update panel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

[image: Snapshot of the issue]![Snapshot of the problem][2]
I have a web form that uses two update panels in the following code below:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div id="SpeciesWrapper" class="RowControl" runat="server">
                        <div class="QuestionColumnControl">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblspecies" runat="server">[$BRAND(LABEL,STAGE1.SPECIES)$]</asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="AnswerColumnControl" title="Please let us know the type of pet you want to insure.">
                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radbtnspecies" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="speciesChanged"
                                RepeatDirection="Horizontal" >
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Cat" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Dog" />
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
                            <label for="radbtnspecies" class="error">
                                Please select your gender</label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Select your Species Type"
                                ControlToValidate="radbtnspecies" EnableClientScript="False"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="PetBreedWrapper" class="RowControl" runat="server">
                        <div class="QuestionColumnControl">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblPetBreed" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ddlPetBreed">[$BRAND(LABEL,STAGE1.PETBREED)$]</asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="AnswerColumnControl">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPetBreed" runat="server" ToolTip="If you can’t find the right breed, please call us as we may still be able to insure your pet." />
                            <span class="errormsg">
                                <cc1:BDML_HighlighterValidator ID="valPetBreed" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlPetBreed"
                                    DivID="PetBreedWrapper" DivCSS="RowControl" ErrorClass="RowControlErr" ForeColor=""
                                    ValidateEmptyText="True" ErrorMessage="[$BRAND(ERROR,STAGE1.PETBREED.REQ)$]"
                                    Display="Dynamic" OnServerValidate="required_ServerValidate" SetFocusOnError="true"> </cc1:BDML_HighlighterValidator>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="radbtnspecies" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The other piece of form which uses update panel is here:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div id="ChippedWrapper" class="RowControl" runat="server">
                        <div class="QuestionColumnControl">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblChipped" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="radChippedYes">[$BRAND(LABEL,STAGE1.CHIPPED)$]</asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="AnswerColumnControl" title="Has your pet been identified with a chip or tag?">
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="radChippedYes" Checked="true" runat="server" GroupName="radChipped"
                                AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="radChippedYes_CheckedChanged" />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblChippedYes" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="radChippedYes">[$BRAND(LABEL,STAGE1.CHIPPEDYES)$]</asp:Label>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="radChippedNo" runat="server" GroupName="radChipped" AutoPostBack="True"
                                OnCheckedChanged="radChippedNo_CheckedChanged" />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblChippedNo" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="radChippedNo">[$BRAND(LABEL,STAGE1.CHIPPEDNO)$]</asp:Label>
                            <%--<img alt="Help" class="help" src="[$BRAND(IMAGELINK,HELP)$]" onmouseover="javascript:showhelpdiv('help-chipped')"
                                onmouseout="javascript:hidehelpdiv('help-chipped')" onmousemove="javascript:movehelpdiv(event,'help-chipped')" />--%>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="ChipNoWrapper" class="RowControl" runat="server">
                        <div class="QuestionColumnControl">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblChipNo" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtChipNo">[$BRAND(LABEL,STAGE1.CHIPNO)$]</asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="AnswerColumnControl">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtChipNo" runat="server" MaxLength="15" />
                            <%--<img alt="Help" class="help" src="[$BRAND(IMAGELINK,HELP)$]" onmouseover="javascript:showhelpdiv('help-chipno')"
                                onmouseout="javascript:hidehelpdiv('help-chipno')" onmousemove="javascript:movehelpdiv(event,'help-chipno')" />--%>
                            <span class="errormsg">

                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="radChippedYes" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I am using external script file and referencing it on the page. Form uses jquery ui tooltip widget on the page load with following code:

```
if ($('body').prop('id') == "youandyourpet") {

$(function () {


    //code to initialize tooltip
    $(document).tooltip();
 });

function pageLoad(sender, args) {

        //code to initialize tooltip
        $(document).tooltip();      
}}
```

Here I am using jquery ready function as well as pageLoad function so that when the update panel's partial rendering takes place, it again ties the controls with tooltip. But I have checked in IE7,8 and latest chrome version that the tooltip remains visible if any of the above radio button are selected which are in the control panel.

![image to show the form problem][3]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have searched a lot on many forums. Also, I am doing correctly but finally I have a very dirty way to solve my issue.

`var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            prm.add_endRequest(function ()
 {  $(".ui-tooltip-content").parents('div').remove();
            });`

Please provide any other solution if anyone is aware of. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

The most elegant solution in my opinion is to run this code:
    $(".ui-tooltip-content").parents('div').remove(); 
in your master page OnLoad();

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp.net ajax and jquery togather, it is good to update your code as following:

```
/*globals jQuery, window, Sys */
(function ($, Sys) {
function setupTooltip()
{
 $(document).tooltip();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
setupTooltip();
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function () {
            setupTooltip();
        });
});
}(jQuery, window.Sys));
```

This will fix the issues you are having.

Comment: I have tried your code but the tooltips still get stuck no matter where the focus is. I have also uploaded the snapshot of the issue.

Comment: are you able to see the image? There are no errors on the page. the only problem is that the tooltips doesn't disappear even if the focus is on any other control.

Comment: in your browser, press F12 and click on console. Refresh your page and see if you are getting any errors or not

Comment: There are 2 errors but its image related 404 not found and not anything related to javascript.

Comment: Any more help for this issue?

Comment: I have found a dirty quick way to solve the issue but it would be great to learn to actually solve the issue. thanx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18621/discussion-between-prashant-lakhlani-and-sidp)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.MyTooltip').tooltip(
            {
                tooltipClass: 'LDFGridCellTooltip',
                open: function (event, ui) {
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                $(ui.tooltip).hide();
                            }, 3000);
                        },
                items: '[data-title]',
                content: function (a) {
                    return $('<span>' + $(this).attr('data-title') + '</span>').html();
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are working with updatePanels, I would advice you to enter your jquery-ui assignment in a pageLoad() function and call this function on document.ready(). Within this function you may call the function that @RealityDysfunction mentioned. So the structure may be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //some stuff that you may have
    pageLoad();        
});


function pageLoad() {
    $(document).tooltip({
        show: {
            effect: "fadeIn",
            duration: 300
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "fadeOut",
            duration: 100
        },
        tooltipClass: "toolTipClass"
    });
    $(".ui-tooltip-content").parents('div').remove();
 };
```

In this way, on every postback that is triggered, you will not lose the jquery-ui widget assingment and you will always remove the tooltip. Optionally you may insert this in a .js file and load it at the end of the document.